# How to stop page refresh on each task addition in my Django To-do app?

Tags: django, django-models, web-applications, django-forms

I am quite new to the web development world and have just built a Todo app using Django. I have used Django `ModelForm` for adding tasks to my `TaskModel`.

Now my problem is that each time I add a task, the whole page refreshes as the added task goes to the database. It is not a very good user experience, as it is refreshing the page on each task addition and also it is taking time for reloading the page. What should I do to stop page refresh but still add the task to the database?

my **views.py** looks something like this:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():  
            form.save()
            all_tasks = TaskModel.objects.all()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    else:
        all_tasks = TaskModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, "todo_list/index.html", {"all_tasks": all_tasks})
```

**Note:** I have used authentication in my todo app so that the tasks can be accessed from any device, so I don't think storing my task merely in the browser cache will work. But I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Back-end

Use [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) so that you can handle the server traffic manually.

### Front-end

You can use a DOM API called `XMLHttpRequest`, but also you can use more easy to use APIs such as [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

When the form event is emitted we have to `e.preventDefault()`.

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();

  // use the same URL in form's action <form action="{{url}}"></form>
  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    data: new FormData(form),
  })
  .then((response)=>{
    return response.json()
  })
  .then((json)=>{
    return console.log(json);
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    console.err(err); // an error occured
  });
});
```

The Django server can respond with a different type of data, `plain/text` or `application/json` are suitable in this situation.

BTW, `fetch` is a function that returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), so you can use `async` and `await` to make you code look better. You can use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), or [JQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to make `XMLHttpRequest` more easy to handle.

Answer (score 1):

Use django-restframework to create the API and then use frontend frameworks like react, vue and etc, to send post request to your Django server, So this way it wouldn't have to reload the page everytime

Comment: This sounds good. Actually, I haven't used any frontend framework in my app yet. So this way the task will be added to my database as well as appear on my frontend without even page reloading, right?

Comment: yep, but you gotta do that in the frontend part to display the submitted data. Another way to get real-time data is by using web-sockets and you can do that with django-channels.

Comment: I don't know much about web-sockets or django-channels but will look into it, thank you.